# NextJS: sidebar routing - currently clicked link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668832/nextjs-sidebar-routing), and found help to make my sidebar links respond by displaying a component in the main div of my page.

Now I want to figure out how to use this where I have more than one option in my sidebar. I added library and tasks, but when I click library - it reveals the library component in the main div (I want this), but when I then click tasks, it reveals both library and tasks components. I only want the tasks component to show in that event.

What is the js command to setState to false if the link is not the most recently clicked link?

```
function Sidebar({ toggleLibrary, toggleTasks }) {
  // const { me, loading } = useMe()
  

  return (
    
            <Stack spacing="1" >
              
              <NavButton label="Tasks"  fontWeight="normal" onClick={toggleTasks} />
              
              <NavButton label="Deals"  fontWeight="normal" onClick={toggleLibrary}/>
            </Stack>
  
  )
}
const DashBase = () => {
    const isDesktop = useBreakpointValue({ base: false, lg: true })
    //  the menu component should initially be hidden
    const [showLibrary, setShowLibrary] = React.useState(false)
    const [showTask, setShowTask] = React.useState(false)

  // state setter to switch between our `true` and `false` states
    const toggleLibrary = () => setShowLibrary(!showLibrary)
    const toggleTasks = () => setShowTask(!showTask)
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
      <Flex
      >

        {isDesktop ? <Sidebar toggleLibrary={toggleLibrary} toggleTasks={toggleTasks} /> : <Navbar />}
  
        <Container py="8" flex="none">
          
          {showLibrary ? <Library /> : '' }
          {showTask ? <Tasks /> : '' }
```

Comment: Do you only ever want one shown at a time? Is that the idea?

Comment: yes - just the component for the one i most recently click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the code has an independent state for each item you want to toggle. While you *could* enqueue state updates to toggle all other states false when a new item is toggled true, this is rather unmaintainable code.

If the goal is to only ever render a single active item then I'd suggest just using a single active state and set the value in a single callback passed to the `Sidebar` component.

Example:

```
const DashBase = () => {
  const isDesktop = useBreakpointValue({ base: false, lg: true });
  //  nothing initially is active
  const [showActive, setShowActive] = React.useState(null);

  // state setter to switch between our `null` and "active" id states
  const toggleActive = (key) => setShowActive(
    active => active === key ? null : key
  );
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <Flex>
      {isDesktop ? <Sidebar toggleActive={toggleActive} /> : <Navbar />}

      <Container py="8" flex="none">
        {showActive === 'library' && <Library />}
        {showActive === 'tasks' && <Tasks />}
        ...
```

...

```
function Sidebar({ toggleActive }) {
  return (
    <Stack spacing="1" >
      <NavButton
        label="Tasks"
        fontWeight="normal"
        onClick={() => toggleActive("tasks")}
      />
      <NavButton
        label="Deals"
        fontWeight="normal"
        onClick={() => toggleActive("library")}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```